# Attach images to knnsearch o/p array

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, pattern-matching, knn

I am working on my project on pattern recognition and i am using knn search for finding nearest neighbors, the problem i am facing is that when i get the o/p in ascending order(Rank's) its some sort of array.

x = [v_2;v_3;v_4;v_5];  Training samples

y = v_1;      sample image

IDX = knnsearch(x,y,'K',4);

o/p

IDX=[2 3 1 4] final o/p

this shows that my 'sample image' matches to 2nd image first, then to third and so on...

So the question is how can i access these array elemnts. I want to attach images to these elements because i want to display these best matched images.

for ex, 
in my database i have images stored img1,img2,img3,img4
as the o/p is
IDX=[2 3 1 4]

it should show me img2 first,, then img3,, then img1,, at last img4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to do is store all the images in a cell. The 3 images are stored in cell called templates. Then using idx select the image. The code is shown below.Images are shown in top down fashion.

```
idx = [3 2 1];  output of knn algorithm
len = length(idx);  
templates = {img1,img2,img3}; images stored in cell
for i = 1:len
        num = idx(i);
        subplot(len,1,i);     
        imshow(templates{num},[]);   shows images as per content of idx
end;
```

I hope this is what you was searching for...

Comment: Thanks! for your help brother; now as per the above code i got my output,really that means a lot! now the problem is these images are displayed vertically on one subplot, now either help me to display these images horizontally or on different figures.

Comment: if you want images to be displayed horizontally on same figure just replace the subplot line with this one. subplot(1,len,i). And if you want images to be displayed in different figures then replace this two lines after num = idx(i);

Comment: yes bro this worked for me! Thank you again for everything you’ve done.